# React hooks add mapped checkbox values to array or remove it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I tried some solutions on the net but cant fix it so i need to ask. I have checkboxes which is mapped in render. I want to add the values of the checkboxes to array state if checked or remove the value if unchecked. Thanks for helps Things i tried ;

My jsx ;

```
{props.edit && <input type="checkbox" value={props.id} onChange={(e) => setDeleteId(e)}/>}
```

Functions ;

```
  const [deleteId, setdeleteId] = useState([]);

  const setDeleteId = (e) => {
    setdeleteId([...deleteId, e.target.value]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(deleteId);
  }, [deleteId])
```

Comment: You say "checkboxes" but then your code only has one checkbox. Can you post a codesandbox that demos the issue?

Comment: Its in a array map. So there are multiple checkboxes. Sorry for uncomplete code.

Comment: Can you post some complete code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler looks like it's always just *adding* the checkbox `id` to the state - you need to also remove it when the checkbox gets unchecked, e.g. -

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

const handleChange = event => {
    const { checked, value } = event.currentTarget;

    setSelected(
      prev => checked
        ? [...prev, value]
        : prev.filter(val => val !== value)
    );
};
```

[Here is a demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bpqulr) showing how it all fits together.